# Custom Tabs "Specified child already has a parent"

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I attempting to create custom tabs using [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136).  But when I try to create an instance of the TextView from the inflated layout and use it as the View in my TabHost.TabSpec, I receive

"Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Main.cs

```
public class Main : TabActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Intent[] intents = new Intent[3];
        intents[0] = new Intent(this, typeof(Inspection)).PutExtra("Name", "Inspection");
        intents[1] = new Intent(this, typeof(Transfer)).PutExtra("Name", "Transfer");
        intents[2] = new Intent(this, typeof(ServiceCalls)).PutExtra("Name", "Service Calls");

        foreach (var intent in intents)
        {
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            TextView tv = getView(intent.GetStringExtra("Name"));
            TabHost.TabSpec spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(intent.GetStringExtra("Name")).SetIndicator(tv).SetContent(intent);
            TabHost.AddTab(spec);
        }

        TabHost.CurrentTab = 0;
    }

    private TextView getView(string text)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tabs_bg, (ViewGroup)FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content));            
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabsText);
        tv.Text = text;

        return tv;
    }
}
```

tabs_bg.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView android:id="@+id/tabsText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background ="@drawable/tab_selector"
    android:textSize="18dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I replace

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabsText);
```

in getView with

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

Then I do not receive that error.  So it definitely seems to have something to do with tabsText in tabs_bg even though that is exactly the way the author did it in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you are porting from does not return the **TextView** from **createTabView**, it returns the **LinearLayout**.  You are returning **tv** instead of **v** in **getView**.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
View v = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tabs_bg, null);
```